# Add category title to product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I'd like to add the category title to the product view page in Magento. I have the following code that currently pulls the category banner to the product view page:

```
<?php
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
        $_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
        $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }
?>
    <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
        <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Can I adapt the above so the category title is also displayed?

Comment: you want to disable category title in listing page right

Comment: No, I'd like to add the category title to the product view page.

Comment: can you plz show me that page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $_category->getName();
```

That should do it!